# How to deduce equations 3.6.15 in Polchinski's string theory book?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory

In polchinski's first course on string, with

[image]

how to deduce[image]

Comment: Related post http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/73393/

Comment: Thanks,but i don't know how can the term $e^{\omega (\sigma)}$ in the equation(1) make it satisfy the geodesic constraint