# Higher-order Weyl dependence of geodesic distance

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory

[image]

This is a screenshot from Polchinski String Theory Vol 1. Can anyone please explain how to derive these identities ?

Comment: Without the book, no one can understand this question because you have not defined $\delta_W$ or $\alpha’$ or $\omega$. Also, scans of text and math are against the guidelines for this site.

Comment: @G.Smith - $\delta_W$ is a Weyl transformation, $g \to e^{2\omega} g$, $\partial_a = \frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma^a}$ and $\Delta(\sigma,\sigma') = \frac{\alpha'}{2} \log d^2(\sigma,\sigma')$ where $d(\sigma,\sigma')$ is the geodesic distance w.r.t. tw-dimensional metric $g$ between points $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$. $\alpha'$ is a parameter.

Comment: This has been answered in detail in https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/73393/a-question-about-the-higher-order-weyl-variation-for-the-geodesic-distance?rq=1

Comment: @Oбжорoв  I am most grateful.